# Is there a way to alter the colors used in TTY consoles on Linux?

Tags: linux, colors, console, tty

By "alter colors", I mean something like change black from `#000000` to `#111111`, and by "TTY console", I mean what you get when you do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> from X11, not a terminal emulator like `xterm` or `urxvt`.

I'm using Arch Linux, but I think it has more to do with the program providing the TTY (`agetty`, I think).

Comment: Terminals don't operate in terms of hex colors - they use color codes like those found in "/etc/shell-colors".

Comment: @new123456 - I don't have any file called "shell-colors" anywhere under `/`

Comment: Huh. You don't state your distribution here - I am running Zenwalk, so you're distribution may vary. Search for `color in bash` to get a list of all the escapes.

Comment: @new123456 - I did mention that I was using Arch, and I'm not looking for bash escape sequences for colors, like `\e[0;30m` for black, I'm looking for a way to customize the actual color for each named color.

Comment: 1. Sorry - I look at tags first ;) 2. Just information, not entirely pertinent to the question but pertinent to the domain.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The *setterm* command is what you're looking for.

```
setterm -foreground black -background white
```

**EDIT**

No, there is no way to alter the names of the colors as you requested.  They are not referenced that way anywhere in curses, terminfo, or the terminal itself.  You could change the definitions of the color indexes (0-15 i think) by editing the kernel source and recompiling.

Comment: No, that is *not* what I'm looking for. I want to change the definitions of colors, not the foreground and background color.

Comment: Consider the following complement of this valid answer https://superuser.com/a/1716448/1024056

Answer (score 14):

This is entirely possible and is something I do on my Arch setup.

You could drop something like this in a shell script and have it run at login:

```
if [ "$TERM" = "linux" ]; then
    echo -en "\e]P0151515" # Black
    echo -en "\e]P1ac4142" # Red
    ...
    echo -en "\e]PEac4142" # Bright Cyan
    echo -en "\e]PFac4142" # Bright White
    clear # Clear artifacts
fi
```

The `\e]P0` to `\e]PF` (base 16) are the escape sequences you need to set the 16 (8 half bright, 8 bright) colours. After which you put your desired replacement colour e.g. `151515`.

Comment: doesn't seem to work in ubuntu 16.04 with bash fwiw

Comment: Since `echo -en` is not POSIX shell compliant (POSIX does not define a `-e` argument for `echo`), a more portable method would be to use `printf` with an octal escape, such as `printf "\033]P0151515"`. `\033` is equivalent to the `0x1b` character that `\e` outputs in bash with `echo -e`. If you don't use bash as your primary shell, that is.

Answer (score 2):

This is the best command I know of:

```
setterm -clear all -foreground green -bold -store
```

You can only have 8 different color as far as I can tell. Maybe some more by using bright in front of basic 8?

Answer (score 1):

How an extra addition: the [current valid answer](https://superuser.com/a/314061/1024056) about

```
setterm -foreground black -background white
```

is valid and works, it has one advantage, it allows customize any color you like, the disadvantage is that is temporal, if you run either `htop` or `w3m <url>` and exit, then the `tty` returns to the original setting.

if you use (according with `man setterm`)

```
setterm --inversescreen [on|off]
```

it applies an inversion of colors between `foreground` and `background` from white/black to black/white respectively. The advantage is that is permanent, you can run either `htop` or `w3m <url>` and exit, then the `tty` keeps the inverted setting yet. The disadvantage is that the colors can't be customized - it means white and black are always used